# Java - Some images won't load with ImageIO

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have about 15 images in a class folder in my Java project. 12 of them will load correctly. 3 of them won't. The files aren't corrupted. How do I fix this?

Comment: Come on, man you should be used to this by now! For better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: I have had multiple issues with sscce's, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I have turned it into an applet inside a web page, but now I get this: `"Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "defensebg.png" "read")".`

Comment: `AccessControlException` A subject for a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images types are often 'container formats', meaning that they might use a number of different encoding internally to encode an image.  For that reason, `ImageIO` might support loading some images of that file-type, but not others.

> The files aren't corrupted.

How do you know that?  Typically paint and media programs will go to extraordinary lengths to load images and other media that are corrupt.  If they can do it, there will usually be no dialog or warning that the file is corrupt (the end user does not care when the image is on-screen).

---

If these are application resources, the solution might be to open them in your favorite paint program, make a trivial change, then save them fresh.  Better image editors will write a valid non-corrupt image, and might also allow you to specify the encoding used, or automatically use a common encoding that Java supports.